# Can I see when I bugfix for Windows 10 is due to be released?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have [encountered this bug here (WSL #330)](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/330). It's an issue with running Linux binaries on Windows Subsystem for Linux.

The github thread says that it is fixed in [Build 17017](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-17017), which [the blog says is available for the Windows Insider Program](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/10/13/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17017-pc/).

I'm not using the Insider Program. Is it possible to see when/if the build will be included in a public update?

Comment: Windows 10 build 17017 is an earlier version of the next big [Feature Update](https://blogs.windows.com/business/2017/04/20/windows-office-align-feature-release-schedules-benefit-customers/), which is [version 1803](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history#Version_1803).  It is scheduled to be released in the March/April time frame, but there isn't a firm date just yet.

Comment: I suspect 1803 will be released in April, not March since we have not heard anything (as of yet) about a March date.  Releases have been restricted to the first week in a month (as of yet)